# Reflections from both edges of a finite well

Tags: quantum-mechanics, wavefunction, schroedinger-equation, scattering, reflection

In section 11.3.1 in Richard Robinnett's Quantum Mechanics book, it says that in the case of transmission resonance ($T=1$), there's complete destructive interference between waves reflected from the first edge, and those transmitted, then reflected from the secone edge, then trnasmitted again. It also says that a phase change takes place in the first reflection, but no phase change happens in the second. I don't understand this statement. I tried arguing from wave mechanics that if the speed of the wave in the reflecting medium (the well) is less than its speed in the first medium, then a $180°$ phase change takes place. But the speed of the wave inside the well should be greater than outside, which means the phase change should happen on reflection from the second edge, not the first.